# How to insert a data validation to cells with data already inputted

Tags: excel, validation

Is it possible to insert data validation to cell already with data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but they will not be revalidated until you edit the data in the cell.

Comment: but is there a way to copy data validation rule without having to edit the data in the cells?

Comment: you can copy a cell that has data validation and then only paste the validation rules using paste special > validation